# reduce time to load image base64 string

Tags: image, base64, reduce

How can I reduce the load time of a base64 image? Image is 1919x977 and weighs 518kb.

This is what I have already done to reduce the load time:

- Use an online tool to reduce the weigth without modifying the quaility and resolution.

I can't think more ways to load it faster.
I have 10mb contacted (in other words, I can download maximum 1mb/s) and even so it takes like almost 14 seconds to load the image.

Comment: What is the format of the image? Are you compressing the bas64 encoding?

Comment: original format is png, and yes, i use base64 encoding to encode the .png image

Comment: Yes. But when you serve it, are you using a COMPRESSING stream? Note that Bas64 encoding is not compression.

Comment: i don't know what you are talking about, i have simply used this website (http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter) which i can upload an image and returns loooong code like this: <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA....../>